# ASP.NET MVC 5 / WebAPI 2 / Xamarin / AngularJS / Solution Visual Studio

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, asp.net-mvc-5

I have currently a visual studio that contains 3 projects :

- MyApp.Models : Contains all my models with Code-First migrations
- MyApp.Web : Contains my main website, only with MVC
- MyApp.Pass : Contains a subdomain website, for customers.

We have new projects and we need to have those things :

- A WebAPI that can be consumes by my main website, my pass website, a backoffice website, and a mobile application
- a backoffice website that consumes WebApi, built with AngularJS
- A mobile application that consumes WebApi, built with Xamarin

How can i layer my visual studio solution to only have one WebAPI that can be consume by all my differents websites/mobile app ?

Best regards,

Comment: umm I'm not really sure i understand the question here?  you can consume a web api project from anywhere.  You don't even need the project in the same solution, it just has to be active and you can call it from any other solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently building a side project - viewingbooker.com which is exactly the setup you are looking for.

What you need to bare in mind is that web api and mvc website have 2 different authentication techniques. Web Api 2 makes amazingly easy to authorise users from eg. xamarin mobile apps. Token is issued and is generally valid for 14 days of inactivity.

I have few projects within my solutions. Most importantly you need a separate project for your business logic. I also use DI to test my business logic as I go.

For website, I serve data as JSON from standard Controllers. For my mobile app, I have a separate web api project that serves the data separately. They both use business logic project so it keeps code redundancy to the minimum.

Remember that mobile app is not a website which you can quickly fix. If you end up using the same models and controllers for website and mobile apps, any change you make will brake your mobile apps and not all users have auto upgrade feature switched on on their mobile devices.

So I recommend you have a standard website with its own models and controllers, which is consumed by angular/knockout etc. Web API 2 project with its own models and controllers. Business logic project in the form of different services accessible by its interfaces so it's easier to test it. And don't get too paranoid with code redundancy that is different controllers, models for website/mobile. This approach will save you a lot of headache in the future - talking from experience.

Comment: Ok so i can have something like this :

- MyApp.Web (MVC 5 App that consumes a WebAPI)
- MyApp.WebPass (MVC 5 App that consumes a WebAPI)
- MyApp.WebBackOffice (MVC 5 App that consumes a WebAPI)
- MyApp.MobileApp (Xamarin project taht consumes a WebAPI)
- MyApp.Models (All Code-First classes with Migrations)
- MyApp.WebAPI (The WebAPI that all my projects will use)

Comment: No, not quite. Have your business logic in a separate project. Treat both MyApp.Web and MyApp.WebAPI as data access points that both talk to your business logic and return data. MVC 5 should not consume WebAPI etc.